# sqlite3.connect not working with relative path

Tags: python, sqlite, database-connection, operationalerror

While using a relative path, I'm getting an error with Sqlite3: OperationalError: unable to open database file,

But with an absolute path it works well. Below are the samples:

```
#database_filepath = 'Data/DatabaseFile.db'

def load_data(database_filepath):
    
    con = sqlite3.connect(database_filepath) #not working
    #con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.abspath(database_filepath)) #working fine

    df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from someTable', con)
```

Is there any better way doing it?

Comment: Relative path should work. Please check your working directory, and if there is a sub dir named Data.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes work fine in my computer. Please check your working directory by:

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath('.'))
```

Then check if there is a sub dir `./Data` existed.

```
print(os.path.isdir('./Data'))
```

If not, you should create this dir first. sqlite will not do it automatically.

Comment: I have already verified that Data directory and the file are present.